# Android showing only drawable of TextView but not the Text

Tags: android

I've made a "menù" in my BottomSheetDialog the issue is that in the preview all is shown correctly but when i test if on a real device some of TextViews just does not shows the `Text`!

[image]

Here is the XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="96dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:text="Coca cola 330ml"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Quantità"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_calculate"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/meno"
                android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_remove_24"
                android:contentDescription="Meno"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
                app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/qta"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/piu"
                android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
                android:contentDescription="Più"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Variante libera"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_restaurant_24"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Variante libera"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_fastfood_24"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Stampa"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_print_24"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:checked="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Elimina"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

While on a real device it's shown as the following:

[image]

Comment: You're using `tools:text` instead it should be `android:text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your TextView tags are using the `tools:text` attribute:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:text="Elimina"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete"
    android:drawablePadding="16dp"/>
```

The `tools` namespace is specifically designed to take effect in the Android Studio layout editor preview window, but be ignored when the app is actually run. This lets you put in placeholder values to make writing the XML easier, without affecting the app's behavior.

Change these to `android:text` and the text will appear when you run the app.

Comment: Damn missed that particular during the compare of two..